# Python variable inheritance/links

Tags: python

I observed something weird/new to me, which certainly comes handy in the moment, however I'd like to understand what's happening in the background, to avoid unwanted modification of variables.

Take the code below (add_actual_wat_columns function), I create a new variable from a dictionary value (wat_days), modify it, and without actually putting it back in the original dictionary (df_dict), the original dictionary will also be updated.

Is this specific to pandas or a generic Python feature? If so, how can I avoid it when I need to?

Bonus question: is there a better way to typehint variable types so the syntax highlighting/autocomplete works properly in VSCode?

```
def main():
    file = "wapd_le.xlsx"
    raw = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0, 1])
    df_cols = list(raw.columns.unique(level=0))
    df_cols.pop(0)
    df_list = []

    for i in df_cols:
        df_list.append(raw["Vendor data"].join(raw[i]))
    df_dict = dict(zip(df_cols, df_list))

    print(df_dict.keys())
    sum_rows(df_dict)
    add_actual_wat_columns(df_dict)
    write_to_excel(df_dict)


def add_actual_wat_columns(df_dict: dict):
    """Creates proper WAT columns for each period.

    Base report from Cashcube sums FI doc payment terms, this function divides that value
    by the monthly FI doc count, adding new columns to the WAT Days dataframe.

    Args:
        df_dict (dict): contains dataframe descriptions as keys and dataframes as values.
    """
    # TODO refactor to have toggle for WAPD/WAT and add proper columns to either (both?) sheet.
    wat_days: pd.DataFrame
    wat_days = df_dict["WAT Days"]
    periods = list(wat_days.columns)[2:]
    actual_wat_periods = [str(x) + " actual WAT" for x in periods]
    wat_days[actual_wat_periods] = wat_days[periods].div(
        df_dict["Count (FI Document Number)"][periods]
    )
    wat_days["Sum actual WAT"] = wat_days[actual_wat_periods[0:-1]].mean(
        axis=1, numeric_only=True
    )
    wat_days.rename(columns={"Sum actual WAT": "Avg actual WAT"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Python variables are names pointing to objects. If you point to an existing object from a new name, both names will point to the same object.

Comment: @Anentropic I believe this is called aliasing? For the author, to stop this behavior, you need to to make a deep-copy of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your object is mutable, you are mutating it.*

```py
wat_days = df_dict["WAT Days"] # wat_days is the object in df_dict
...
wat_days[actual_wat_periods] = ... # modify that object.
```

Another example:

```py
things = {1: 2, 2: [3]}
x = things[1]
x += 1
y = things[2]
y[0] += 1
y += [1]
z = things[2][0]
z += 1
print(things)
# {1: 2, 2: [4, 1]}
```

do you see what is going on?
If you need an new copy of a mutable object, have a look at [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

*Note that this is perhaps a backwards explanation---it's just that `x` and `z` are modified by `+` by being replaced.  The name-to-object binding works in the same way for `x` `y` and `z`.

Comment: this answer is fine, but this phrase is not quite right: _"If you need an immutable copy of a mutable object"_ ... if you `copy` a mutable object you will get back a mutable object

Comment: @Anentropic yes, what I wrote is plain wrong, sorry.  Copy returns a copy.  I'll correct it.

Comment: So the the two variables are permanently linked as they are pointing to the same object in memory unless I specifically do something about it. Kind of unexpected, but now that I know what's going on I can deal with it as needed. It was a bit confusing, as I thought local/global variable scope will prevent this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @Asrakh it often does confuse people coming to python.  In fact it has nothing to do with scope: scope concerns variable *names*, not the targets they are bound to.  It's rather that in python `var = thing` is a *name binding*, not an implicit copy.  This behaviour is hidden with things like strings and ints, because modifying them makes the name point at a *new* object, so it can go unnoticed for quite a long time.  If you come from a language with pointers, consider the assignment as being more like getting a pointer to the object than getting its value. (this is only an analogy)